# t/sql query with two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

i need to create an oracle select statement that returns acct,name,city,splitcost from table1 and APIcost from table2.  table1 splits the 90 into 3 diff. amounts because they are distributed elsewhere.  table2 is the API download that only has 1 record of the total 90.  if i use inner join the 90 repeats on each row linking by acct.  i need the results to look like the second view only show APIcost total 90. once per acct.
hope this makes sense.  if i was using sql I'm prob. do a temp table but it has to be done in Oracle which i'm not used too.

Comment: This sort of thing should really be handle in the display layer, as it leads to horrible SQL. But if you are sure you need to do it in SQL, what is the criteria for deciding which `table1` record has the `apicost`?

Comment: the first occurrence of the matching acct.  1111.  I would like to do it code, but they want all data calls from oracle.  i'm not worried about the footer total. i get that from my grid.

Comment: But how you know **which** occurrence is *"the first occurrence"*? Is there some other column which determines order?

Comment: there are no other columns to key on.  as long as apicost shows only once for each acct.  In SQL i would probably load all the rows in a temp table than loop thru. and call table2 apicost.  add a param. flag bit to turn on off for each acct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a temp table, just build a rank and do a case statement on it to populate the first row with the api_cost. I don't know which row you want, so play with the "order by" clause to get that to do the row you want.

```
/* Building out your data to a "temp table" */
with table1 as
(select 1111 as acct, 'john' as name, 'hampton' as city, 30 as split_cost, 90 as 
api_cost from dual union all
select 1111 as acct, 'john' as name, 'hampton' as city, 40 as split_cost, 90 as 
api_cost from dual union all
select 1111 as acct, 'john' as name, 'hampton' as city, 20 as split_cost, 90 as 
api_cost from dual union all
select 1111 as acct, 'john' as name, 'hampton' as city, 20 as split_cost, 90 as 
api_cost from dual)
/* You need nothing above here, just below */
select acct, name, city, split_cost, 
case when rank() over (partition by acct, name, city  order by split_cost, rownum) = 
1 then api_cost
     else null
     end as api_cost
from table1; --substitute your table name here

OUTPUT:
ACCT    NAME    CITY    SPLIT_COST  API_COST
1111    john    hampton 20          90
1111    john    hampton 20  
1111    john    hampton 30  
1111    john    hampton 40
```